# using CSS Transform to make div bigger, but can't seem to get other divs to move

Tags: javascript, css

So I have this little bit of code making a div bigger on mouseover,

```
        $('.resumeBox').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).css("transform","scale(2)");
        });
        $('.resumeBox').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).css("transform","scale(1)");
        });
```

The problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to get the other divs to move out of it's way. I've tried every position or display I can think of, but they just keep getting overlapped.

If I am explaining it poorly, here it is isolated.
https://codepen.io/seanmc10/pen/XOwLbJ

Comment: Transformed elements are taken out of the textflow, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform ("_the object will act as a containing block for any `position: fixed` elements that it contains_").

Comment: When you transform, the original dimension do not change because it is taken out of the flow. If you just want to grow it, you can change the width and height and put a transition on the element so it animates. This way the content will move out of way

Answer (score 1):

No use `transform: scale()` use `witdh and height`

**HTML**

```
<button onclick=doThing()>Click to do thing</button>
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="box2">I want this to move down not get covered up </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box{
  background-color: red;  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: 500ms ease-in;
}
#box2{
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var c = 0;
var initialValue = 100;
function doThing(){
  if (c==1){
    //the if statement is just resetting the       box if already big
    $('#box').css({
      height: (initialValue + (initialValue / 2 )) + 'px',
      width: (initialValue + (initialValue / 2 )) + 'px'
    });
    c = 0;
  } else {
    $('#box').css({
      height: initialValue+'px',
      width: initialValue+'px',
    });
    c=1;
  }
}
```